# How can I find all cards with flavor text from a certain set and colour?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

How can I find all the cards from the Khans of Tarkir block (Khans / Fate Reforged / Dragons of Tarkir) that have flavor text? Preferably, I'd like to search just red and black cards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A gatherer search for the vowels in flavour text with the block and colors you want selected in the gatherer advanced search feature will find you what you're looking for, since all english words must contain a,e,i,o,u or y. [Here are all 146 red and/or black cards with flavour text from Khans block](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?page=0&sort=abc+&action=advanced&set=|[%22Khans%20of%20Tarkir%22]|[%22Fate%20Reforged%22]|[%22Dragons%20of%20Tarkir%22]&color=%20@(|[R]|[B])&flavor=|[a]|[e]|[i]|[o]|[u]|[y]).

Note that the colors are added as OR, meaning it has to be at least red or at least black, if they were added as AND it would only find colors that are both. The no other colors is added using the exclude unselected terms more color option. (so it won't find cards that are black and blue for instance)

UPDATE - gatherer does have an issue in it's matching on empty spaces and block vs set matching. updated image and link for better

[image]

Comment: For information sake, the playable with only these colors is used to handle hybrid mana symbols, so it will allow for example a blue and black card like [Nightveil Specter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366242) when searching for Rakdos colored cards.

Comment: Gatherer search seems to be not too accurate, just looking a bit it seems to have included [Acid-Spewer Dragon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394485) which has no flavour text and misses [Alesha, Who Smiles at Death](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=420736) and [Alesha's Vanguard](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=391788) which does.

Comment: Several cards have 1 word flavour text (Turn to Frog, Lava Axe, etc) although I don't know about in Khans block.

Comment: @Malco Yes I noticed that after, I adjusted for a better search that returned the exact list your Scryfall search returned.

Comment: @TimB Yes, some do exist, my adjusted query will handle that, particularly since it looks like gatherer may store blank flavor text with a space, or trim the ends of a search string. Somehow it matched no flavor text cards with the old search.

Comment: Such an awesome read those flavour texts... thanks for clearing this up for me :)

Comment: NOTE - Gatherer currently does not consider Fate Reforged a part of Khans block, so you need to search by set if you want results for Khans. This has been brought up with WotC's team.

Comment: The "spring" and "summer" printings of [Extremely Slow Zombie](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439443) have vowelless flavor text. So this answer is not fully general (though it seems to work fine for Khans block specifically).

Comment: @Micah yes, those are actually the only two cards in all of magic (I just did a search) that has flavor text with no vowels, I'm willing to accept two versions of a silver bordered card as an insignificant edge case, plus gatherer will still find Extremely Slow Zombie based on the other two variants.

Answer (score 4):

You can check out [this list on Scryfall](https://scryfall.com/search?q=%28e%3Aktk+or+e%3Afrf+or+e%3Adtk%29+ft%3A%22+%22+%28c%3Ar+or+c%3Ab+or+c%3Arb%29), for a bit nicer layout than what gatherer provides.

If you want to tweak it the search term was `(e:ktk or e:frf or e:dtk) ft:" " (c:r or c:b or c:rb)`.

To break down the search for you:

- `(e:ktk or e:frf or e:dtk)`: Show cards in Khans of Tarkir (KTK) **or** Fate Reforged (FRF) **or** Dragons of Tarkir (DTK).
- `ft:" "` show cards with flavour text containing " " (a space). This is effectively any card that has flavour text.
- `(c:r or c:b or c:rb)` show cards that are Red (r) **or** show cards that are Black (b) **or** show cards that are Red and Black (rb).

If you want to learn more about how to modify Scryfall searchs you can check out [the syntax page](https://scryfall.com/docs/reference).

---

As per Murgatroid99's comment, you can also use the more compact search string:
 `b:ktk c<=rb -c:c ft:/\w/`.

> This searches for the Khans block, with no colors other than red or black, and not colorless, with flavor text checking a regular expression match for any letters or numbers.

Comment: Gatherer gives 149 results, Scryfall gives 145, I haven't looked the results over but I am betting the difference is the ones that are (c:r and c:b), there's exactly 4 of those with flavor text

Comment: Addendum to previous comment - I looked at the scryfall results, and yes it definitely does exclude the gold cards. `(c:r or c:b or (c:r and c:b))` doesn't seem to fix the problem,

Comment: @Andrew I am only seeing one rb card boltwing. What are the others?

Comment: @Andrew I suspect this might be because I am searching based on set, and you are searching based on block

Comment: @Andrew, it turns out gatherer just doesn't do a good job of searching, just by comparing lists, gatherer search includes [Acid-Spewer Dragon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394485) which has no flavour text and misses [Alesha, Who Smiles at Death](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=420736) and [Alesha's Vanguard](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=391788)

Comment: Yes I corrected that, Gatherer seems to ignore whitespace in the text search, as a search without the " " flavor condition returns the same list.

Comment: You can do this a bit more simply with `b:ktk c<=rb -c:c ft:/\w/`. This searches for the Khans block, with no colors other than red or black, and not colorless, with flavor text checking a regular expression match for any word characters.

Comment: And these cards (which do include a few that aren't *actually* flavor text) are the ones you miss by looking for spaces instead of word characters: https://scryfall.com/search?q=ft%3A%2F%5Cw%2F+-ft%3A"+"+

Comment: @murgatroid99 that gives back 147 cards, interestingly.

Comment: The block search appears to include supplemental sets related to the block, which seems to be why that happened.

Answer (score -3):

If you go to the advanced section of [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Advanced.aspx) it lets you pick a multitude of different options, including all of what you are looking for.

Comment: There's not an obvious way to search for only cards that have flavour text, and this answer doesn't provide one either.

Comment: I guess it seemed obvious to me, but I'm probably making the assumption that people would realise an empty string as mentioned in the answer above would give the answer. I blame mysellf for thinking if you're on stack overflow you are 100% a programmer.

Comment: I'm a programmer, and there are times when I've asked for help only to be shown the obvious solution that I shouldn't have missed. But that doesn't stop me from asking for help.

Comment: @JoshGordon Except this isn't stack overflow, it's stack exchange, If this were SO yes you can assume safely a poster is a programmer, but don't assume what's obvious answer wise to you is obvious to everyone, that's why SO and SE in general exist. Other SE sites come up in google a lot, don't assume every SE user also is on SO.

Comment: @Andrew yeah I get it now, it was a mistake on my part. I've started trying to get involved more on overflow and exchange more recently, so forgive my errors. I'll make sure not to make the same mistake again

Comment: A short side not... I do believe I have an account on SO but I rarely ever use it because of the expectations and more often than not the bigotry from some users on that site. Obviously has no baring on this site and its users though.